# Post API Call from Jetpack compose using Retrofit and hilt ViewModel in MVVM Please guys

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

now I am working with jetpack compose I have to make API calls for app I got get Data from API but
POST the Data to the API I am facing Trouble Please help me guys I am using MVVM and Retrofit and
HiltViewModel

Comment: https://github.com/nameisjayant/Notesss-Compose , check this github repository you will understand how to do Get , Post , Put and Delete request

Answer (score 0):

**ApiService.kt**

```
@POST("todo/")
    suspend fun addNotes(
        @Body note: Note
    ): NoteResponse
```

**Repository.kt**

```
 override suspend fun addNote(note: Note): Flow<NoteResponse> = flow {
        emit(retrofitService.addNotes(note))
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
```

**NoteEvent file**

```
sealed class NoteEvents {

    data class AddNoteEvent(val data: Note) : NoteEvents()
}

sealed class NoteUiEvents {

    data class Success(val data:NoteResponse) : NoteUiEvents()
    data class Failure(val msg:String) : NoteUiEvents()
    object Loading : NoteUiEvents()

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val _addNoteEvent: MutableSharedFlow<NoteUiEvents> = MutableSharedFlow()
    val addNoteEvent = _addNoteEvent.asSharedFlow()

   fun onEvent(events: NoteEvents) {
        when (events) {
            is NoteEvents.AddNoteEvent -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.addNote(events.data)
                        .onStart {
                            _addNoteEvent.emit(
                                NoteUiEvents.Loading
                            )
                        }.catch {
                            _addNoteEvent.emit(
                                NoteUiEvents.Failure(it.message ?: "Something went wrong")
                            )
                        }.collect {
                            _addNoteEvent.emit(
                                NoteUiEvents.Success(it)
                            )
                        }
                }
            }
}
}
```

**Composable screen**

fire this event on button click

```
if (title.isNotEmpty() && description.isNotEmpty()) {
            viewModel.onEvent(
                NoteEvents.AddNoteEvent(
                    Note(title, description)
                )
            )
```

handle response in launch effect

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    viewModel.addNoteEvent.collectLatest {
        isLoading = when (it) {
            is NoteUiEvents.Success -> {
                context.showToast("Note Added")
                noteDialog = false
                viewModel.onEvent(NoteEvents.ShowNotes)
                false
            }
            is NoteUiEvents.Failure -> {
                Log.d("main", "NoteScreen:${it.msg} ")
                context.showToast(it.msg)
                false
            }
            NoteUiEvents.Loading -> true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, then I tried sending my post request as Multipart instead of Body and it worked,

```
@Multipart
@POST(todo/)
suspend fun addNote(
    @Part ("note_id") noteId: RequestBody,
    @Part ("note") note: RequestBody
): Response<NoteResponse>
```

then call it like this in your repository implementation:

```
fun addNote(note: Note): Response<NoteResponse> {

    val noteId= note.note_id.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    val note= note.note.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    return api.addNote(noteId, note)
}
```